# Terminology for conditions on the negation of relations.

Tags: terminology

Suppose you have a relation $R$ and you want to impose the condition upon the relation $\lnot R$ that it be (e.g.) transitive. What would be a good terminology in this case? Would $counter transitive$ or $counter \ transitive$ be good suggestions?

Comment: You might consider "cotransitive", by analogy with words like "cofinite", in which "co" refers to the complement.  I would not, however, consider this or either of your suggestions to be "good terminology", and I'm not sure there's any really good terminology.  Do you really *need* a name for this?

Comment: It is for some exploration I am doing where I would invoke the term for the idea several times, so my judgement is that a term would be useful. I agree that $cotransitive$ is a better term, and I appreciate its connection to related usage.